# jquery ajax send data and serverside script run correctly but give error 500

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, internal

when i click button send data to php script
and proccess it successfully and update database but give me 500 internal server error

```
        function like_post(i){
        var id1=i;
        $.ajax({url:"like.php",type:'post',data{id:id1},success:function(result){
        alert("sucsses");
        },error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request+status+error);
        }});  

        }
```

it,s my php script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$id=$_POST['id'];
$conn=new mysqli("localhost","telegram_admin","Taher1375","telegram_db");
$likesql="UPDATE group1 SET like1=like1+1 WHERE id='".$id."'";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $likesql)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "failed";
}
$mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: 501 and 500 are different response types. Can you please fix either the title or question content to be accurate.

Comment: i'm error it's 500 error

Answer (score 1):

Remove $ from mysqli_close function.

it should be

> mysqli_close($conn)